# How do I prevent resizing of particular buffer?

Tags: buffers, statusline, plugin-airline

I have these mappings in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <s-j> <C-w>-
nnoremap <s-k> <C-w>+
```

In a single buffer, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> results in resizing my (pic1) buffer. Im not sure about that, but i think the airline "statusline" is a seperate buffer.

Anyways, how can i prevent that?

**EDIT:** Sorry, i forgot that i can edit my own questions.
In the link above (I can only post 2 links), the airline buffer is very similiar to mine before resizing - (pic2) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, the location of the buffer has changed. I want just that the airline buffer is always as in the one before, that it's always at the bottom.

@Nobe4 Thanks for the link, im not sure if that's what im searching for, but i'll try it.

**EDIT2**: The Only difference between the two pictures is the positioning of the airline buffer. In [1](http://s30.postimg.org/q6c4wdj7l/2015_08_11_111422_800x881_scrot.png) it's at the very bottom, like it should be. In [2](http://s29.postimg.org/wy3kp8lt3/2015_08_11_111651_800x881_scrot.png) the airline buffer itself is shifted upwards. I.e. in (pic2), between the airline buffer and the very bottom is just nothing. My target is, that the airline buffer on the bottom (if horizontally splitted) can't be shifted upwards like in (pic2), because it's just useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1925046/2558252

Comment: What exactly are you refering to as your "airline buffer"? I don't understand what is resized and shouldn' be, maybe a screenshot would be useful here.

Comment: @statox: Before <S-j>: http://postimg.org/image/5a8f56hcx/


Afterwards: http://postimg.org/image/cgux9tgp1/JK

i want that the second picture isn't possible to achieve, e.g. the buffer should always stay as in picture 1.

Comment: The second image is not found ;-) Also put the screenshots in your question (with the "edit" button, the editor will give you the possibility to add a screenshot that you don't have to host yourself) rather than in the comments please.

Comment: @Nobe4 Do you have an idea, how i could assign "set wfh" and "set wfw" to a particular buffer? I mean, i like the ability to resize the other windows/buffers.

Comment: @toogley, maybe you should remove the link to airline (most of the user know it or can google it has it is a well know plugin) and put 2 screenshots of before/after. Also don't hesitate to circle where the problem is or something like that. Your airline seems pretty normal to me.

Comment: Oh I think I get it: when you have 2 splitted windows you have one airline at the bottom of each window and you would like to have only one at the bottom of your screen. Am I right?

Comment: I think it's simply that his statusline moves up, and the cmd line height grows, while the single window shrinks.

Comment: @VanLaser exactly.

Comment: @toogley I'm not sure but I think the following code should do what you want: http://vpaste.net/PyObW